# Script runs successfully on Spyder but not directly in Python

Tags: python, pyinstaller, spyder

This a conceptual question. What reasons could motivate that a script runs successfully on Spyder IDE but not directly in Python. I am in Win7-64x. I think it is because Spyder is somehow more lenient.. maybe it uses hidden modules, libs, bats..? I found this problem when I was trying to make an executable using Pyinstaller, so I step back and check running the myscript.py on python directly like this on cmd,

```
python myscript.py
```

and it runs the script but throws normal errors like "list index out of range". The thing is they don't appear if executed inside the Spyder IDE, the script in Spyder is run fine without errors. I don't know the possible reasons. There is a way to roundabout that for pyinstaller, so that the produced executable runs fine like in Spyder? Suggestions? (Win7-64x, Python3.6, Spyder3.3.3)

Comment: no one can tell what errors may come before executing. Just tell what error is coming for you.

Comment: Impossible to say. There are ways in which scripts will run in Spyder that really shouldn't in any normal setting. That's because imports are persisted across scripts, as are global names, and it also resolves imports that regular python will not

Comment: Yes, I have seen that Spyder transforms string-path with forward slash '/' into backward '\\' just before been entered into path built-in functions. So I suppose the solution would be to see the final product of Spyder just before be executed by Python. It would be wonderful that the produced myscript.pyc could be used by pyinstaller. In that way the problem would be directly hindered